# How to find a specific word in an URL?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I have a string called "URL" which stores the url which comes dynamically. Now I would like to show whether the url from youtube or vimeo or facebook or google.

String URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0jmSsQ5ptw"; // this comes dynamically in my code

if [URL contains youtube word ]
[
print "URL from YOUTUBE"
]

if [URL contains facebook word ]
[
print "URL from FACEBOOK"
]

if [URL contains google word ]
[
print "URL from GOOGLE"
]

if [URL contains vimeo word ]
[
print "URL from VIMEo"
]

please help me how to find a word in a url.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: have you taken a look at String.contains() /String.indexOf() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `url.contains("whatyouwant")`

ref : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `split()`

```
    String URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0jmSsQ5ptw";
    System.out.println("URL from "+URL.split("\\.")[1].toUpperCase());
```

*Output*:

```
URL from YOUTUBE
```

Answer (score 0):

you already answered your own question.

if [URL contains google word ] [ print "URL from GOOGLE" ]

```
if(URL.contains("google"))
print("URL from GOOGLE")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url.toLowerCase().contains("dynamic code");
system.out.println(url+" from "+ dynamic code;
```